# cannot select collection view cell again unless I touch second tab and come back to main tab

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, cell, collectionview

I have a tabbed application.

I have a collection view. When user taps on collection view cell, a new view displays. When a user closes that view via a touch gesture, the entire view is removed from the super view so you can only see the collection view.

I can now scroll up an down the collection view however I cannot select a new cell even after I deselect all cells when the view is closed.

interestingly, when I click on the second tab and then come back to this tab I can now select a cell again.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Here is my code in my seperate view file that is directly within the class init method:

```
  //set cancel icon properties
    self.escapeIcon.image = UIImage(named: "Ninja")
    self.escapeIcon.image?.roundImage()
    self.escapeIcon.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let closeSelector: Selector = "close:"
    let tapOnIcon = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: closeSelector)
    tapOnIcon.delegate = self
    tapOnIcon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    escapeIcon.userInteractionEnabled = true
    escapeIcon.addGestureRecognizer(tapOnIcon)

    //add to card header
    cardHeader.addSubview(escapeIcon)
    bringSubviewToFront(escapeIcon)
```

Then I create the selector function called "Close:" in the same view file like so:

```
lazy var collectView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView()
var path:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
var celly:CollectionViewCell = CollectionViewCell()

func close(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("execution")
    //unblur animation
    self.superview?.darkUnBlurBackGround(self.superview!, frame: (self.superview?.bounds)!, duration: 1.0)
    //the collectView is a reference pointer to the collectionview in the 
    //view controller file so here I enable scrolling again
    self.collectView.scrollEnabled = true
    //I then remove this "card view" from the superview so that only the collectionview is now visible
    self.removeFromSuperview()
    // I deselect all items in the collectionview and reload everything
    self.collectView.deselectAllItems(true)
    self.collectView.reloadInputViews()
    self.collectView.reloadData()
    self.collectView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}
```

In my view controller file, I do following when the user selects a cell:

```
//Create actions for when a user selects a collection view cell
var currentlySelectedEntrepreneur: Entrepreneur = Entrepreneur()

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //pause scrolling on collection view while cell is selected
    collectionView.scrollEnabled = false

    //animation to blur out background
    collectionView.darkBlurBackGround(collectionView, frame: collectionView.bounds, duration: 0.5)

    //update global entrepreneur variable with entrepreneur instance
    currentlySelectedEntrepreneur = entrepreneurData[indexPath.item]

    //decode image url by name
    let imgURL = imageName[currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.name]

    //Update card view origin based on last content offset value
    cardView.updateCardViewFrameOrigin(0, y: lastContentOffset)
    //add image
    cardView.image.image = imageData[imgURL!]
    //add data with animation
    cardView.cardTitle.setTextWithTypeAnimation(currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.name)
    //add age, company and networth values
    cardView.cardLabelAge.labelDetails.text =  "\(currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.age)"
    cardView.cardLabelCompany.labelDetails.text = currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.company
    cardView.cardLabelNetworth.labelDetails.text = "\(currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.netWorth) \(currentlySelectedEntrepreneur.netWorthDenomination)"

    //reload table data and reset frame
    cardView.myTableView.reloadData()
   // cardView.myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    cardView.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -cardView.myTableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)


    //create a reference to the collectionview from the card view
    cardView.collectView = self.collectionView
    cardView.celly = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    //self.collectionView.deselectAllItems(true)

    collectionView.addSubview(cardView)

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls show us some code?

Comment: Hi Sohil, I have added detailed code of all the parts I think are necessary for you to understand the problem and perhaps offer your solution. Just remember, that this is a tabbed application with 2 tabs.

Comment: anyhelp with this one